# How to return the name of a file from a path and file name using batch file

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

I am trying to run a script that in part sets set a variable called "name" to be only the name of a file from a address field. There will only ever be one file and it will always be in the same location, but the name of the file will change.
I have tried the following:

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /b \\sshserver\SFTP\incoming\Trade Capture Data\Import\Auction Volumes\Auction Volumes*.csv') do @set name=%%G 
echo %name%
```

and

```
for /r  %%f in (\\sshserver\SFTP\incoming\Trade Capture Data\Import\Auction Volumes\Auction Volumes*.csv) do @set name=%%~nf 
echo %name%
```

The location of the file will always be \sshserver\SFTP\incoming\Trade Capture Data\Import\Auction Volumes\ and the file name will always start "Auction Volumes"

I am new to CMD programming and am struggling to understand the FOR command. I have looked through a load of posts and just cant seem to get my head round the best way to do this!

Please help!

Thank you

Comment: I would use forfiles for this. Gives you all the options you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use forfiles for this, given that it does all you want.

Do note that forfiles does not support UNC paths, so you have to map a networkdrive first.

The script would look something like this:

```
    @echo off

::  -- Navigate to the UNC using spare driveletter
    pushd "\\sshserver\SFTP\incoming\Trade Capture Data\Import\Auction Volumes\"

::  -- get filename and store in variable
    forfiles /m "Auction Volumes*.csv" /C "cmd /k set name=@file"

::  -- Return to local path and remove temp driveletter
    popd

::  -- show result
    echo %name%
```